# how obfuscat entire folder js file using gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, node-modules

"Here is my gulpfile.js please let me know what should i have to add in this file to obfuscat all js files"

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const minify = require("gulp-minify");
const JavaScriptObfuscator = require("javascript-obfuscator");

gulp.task("js", function () {
  return gulp
    .src("js/*.js")
    .pipe(gulp.dest("output/"));
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Javascript Obfuscator docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-obfuscator#plugins) directly give you your answer.

They offer [a gulp plugin named `gulp-javascript-obfuscator`](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/gulp-javascript-obfuscator). You'll want to use that instead.

In your example, you'd probably write:

```js
const minify = require('gulp-minify');
const JavaScriptObfuscator = require('gulp-javascript-obfuscator');

gulp.task('js', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('js/*.js')
    .pipe(JavaScriptObfuscator())
    .pipe(minify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('output/'));
});
```

Please try to research these before posting these types of questions, as StackOverflow considers these types of posts to not be "[good](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)."

Comment: suppose I Want to add obfuscator options like    {
        compact: false,
        controlFlowFlattening: true,
        controlFlowFlatteningThreshold: 1,
        numbersToExpressions: true,
        simplify: true,
        shuffleStringArray: true,
        splitStrings: true,
        stringArrayThreshold: 1
    }  then where i can add these options